# Homework: Write a function shampoo_instructions() with parameter num_cycles

Tags: python

The question: Write a function `shampoo_instructions()` with parameter `num_cycles`. If `num_cycles` is less than 1, print `"Too few."`. If more than 4, print `"Too many."`. Else, print `"N : Lather and rinse."` `num_cycles` times, where N is the cycle number, followed by `"Done."`.

Sample output for the given program:
1 : Lather and rinse.
2 : Lather and rinse.
Done.

My code:

```
    def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    if num_cycles < 1:
        print ('Too few.')
    elif num_cyles > 4:
        print ('Too many.')
    else:
        i = 0
        while i<=num_cycles:
            i = i + 1
            print (i+1,": Lather and rinse")

    print ('Done')

shampoo_instructions(2)
```

My code is throwing the following error and I can't seem to figure out how to define `num_cycles`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 14, in 
shampoo_instructions(2)   File "main.py", line 4, in shampoo_instructions
elif num_cyles > 4: NameError: global name 'num_cyles' is not defined
```

Comment: There is a `num_cycles` vs `num_cyles` typo

Answer (score 4):

```
def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    if num_cycles < 1:
        print ('Too few.')
```

This line:

```
    elif num_cyles > 4:
```

Should be:

```
    elif num_cycles > 4:
```

The error goes away after that's fixed. So the rest is syntactically fine. However, I made a couple changes to get your desired output:

```
        print ('Too many.')
    else:
        i = 0
        while i<num_cycles:
            print (i+1,": Lather and rinse")
            i = i + 1

    print('Done')
```

This produces:

```
1 : Lather and rinse
2 : Lather and rinse
Done
```

So you may want `<` rather than `<=` and you were adding 1 to `i` twice before printing it before.

Answer (score 4):

There were several syntax errors and incorrect variables. All have been corrected and the code has been tested. Cheers!

```
def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    if num_cycles < 1:
        print ('Too few.')
    elif num_cycles > 4:
        print ('Too many.')
    else:
        i = 0
        while i < num_cycles:
            print (i+1,": Lather and rinse.")
            i = i + 1

        print('Done.')

shampoo_instructions(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):    
    if num_cycles < 1:
        print ('Too few.')
    elif num_cycles > 4:
        print ('Too many.')
    else:
        n = 0
        while n != num_cycles:
            n = n + 1
            print ( n ,': Lather and rinse.')
       
        
        print ('Done.')

user_cycles = int(input())
print_shampoo_instructions(user_cycles)
```

Comment: This answer helped me the most. I think the readability of the code triumphs the need for the other stuff.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    if num_cycles <= 1:
        print('Too few.')
    elif num_cycles > 4:
        print('Too many.')
    else:
        i = 0
        while i<num_cycles:
            i += 1
            print (i,": Lather and rinse.")
        print('Done.')
```

Comment: Please provide context around your answer rather than providing code snippets that have no explanation or context.

Answer (score -1):

```
def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles): 
    if num_cycles < 1: 
        print('Too few.') 
    elif num_cycles > 4: 
        print('Too many.') 
    else: 
        i = 0 
        while i<num_cycles: 
            i = i + 1 
            print (i,': Lather and rinse.') 
        print('Done.')

shampoo_instructions(2)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value

Answer (score -1):

```
def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    if num_cycles < 1:
        print('Too few.')
    elif num_cycles > 4:
        print('Too many.')
                
    else:
        i = 0
        while i<num_cycles:
            print (i+1,": Lather and rinse.")
            i = i + 1
        print('Done.')

shampoo_instructions(2)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

```
def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    if num_cycles < 1:
        print('Too few.')
    elif num_cycles > 4:
        print('Too many.')
    else:
        i = 0
    while i < num_cycles:
        print (i + 1,': Lather and rinse.')
        i = i + 1
    print('Done.')

user_cycles = int(input())
shampoo_instructions(user_cycles)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```py
def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    if num_cycles < 1:
        print ('Too few')
    elif num_cycles > 4:
        print ('Too many')
    else:
        n = 0
        while n != num_cycles:
            n = n + 1
            print ( n ,':Lather and rinse.')
       
        
        print ('Done.')
```

this is working code. the other answers provide an infinite loop with the use of `<` or `<=` operator in the while statement.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
def print_shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    if num_cycles < 1:
        print('Too few.')
    elif num_cycles > 4:
        print('Too many.')
    else:
        i = 0
        while i < num_cycles:
            print(i + 1, ': Lather and rinse.')
            i = i + 1
    print('Done.')

user_cycles = int(input())
print_shampoo_instructions(user_cycles)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
if num_cycles < 1:
print ('Too few.')
elif num_cycles > 4:
print ('Too many.')
else:
n = 0
while n != num_cycles:
n = n + 1
print ( n ,': Lather and rinse.')

```
    print ('Done.')
```